# Run rate of 20 over Cricket match

Tags: cricket

In 20 over game.... first team scored 152 all out in 16.2 Over and second team scored 153/6 in 17 over.what is the run rate?

Answer (score 1):

The team batting first will always have their run rate calculated for the maximum number of overs they can bat irrespective of the number of overs they have managed to play. 
As in this case, the first team NRR is  7.6 (152/20).

For the second team NRR is dependent on various scenarios.

1. Played for 20 overs without getting all out.In this scenario NRR is
   calculated for entire 20 overs.
2. Chased the target with overs remaning. NRR is calculated for only
   the played overs.
3. Got All out before 20 overs. NRR is calculated for entire 20 overs.

Hence in your case the second team NRR is 9 (153/17)